# LPCWST does not works on Unicode character set

Tags: c++, c

I have application which reads key in registry entry.

Its working good on `Multi-Byte Character Set`

But On `Unicode character set` it cannot open key

This is my code:

```
HKEY hkey = 0;
    char buf[255] = {0};
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
    const char* subkey_x64 = "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\UCP";
    const char* subkey_x86 = "SOWTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\UCP";

    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, (LPCWSTR)subkey_x64, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        dwType = REG_SZ;
        if (RegQueryValueEx(hkey, (LPCWSTR)"DisplayIcon", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            cout << "Key Value IS: " << buf << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Cannot get key value..." << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Cannot open key\n" << endl << endl;
        RegCloseKey(HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA);
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea why it cannot open key?

(LPCWSTR) is not good approach?

Im using visual studio 2010

Comment: Another good example showing why "*Thou shalt not cast!*" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const char*` is not an Unicode string. Change to `const wchar_t*` and you won't need a cast.

With the cast you say the compiler to interpret that address as a pointer to an Unicode string but it's not.

Moreover when you declare an Unicode string literal you should use `L` prefix: `L"DisplayIcon"` (again no need for a cast). If your code may run both on Unicode and multi-byte you may use the `TEXT()` macro to do the trick for you (or its short version `_T()`): `_T("DisplayIcon")`.

Answer (score 2):

Make the string literals wide string literals by changing type to `wchar_t*` and prefixing the literal with an `L`:

```
const wchar_t* subkey_x64 =
   L"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\UCP";
const wchar_t* subkey_x86 =
   L"SOWTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\UCP";
```

No requirement to cast the variables in the registry function calls, and remember to prefix any other string literals with `L`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just case `const char *` to `LPCWSTR`, because these are pointers to different types. You either need to convert your `const char *` to `LPCWSTR` using the `MultiByteToWideChar` function, or instead use:

```
LPCWSTR subkey_x64 = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\UCP");
LPCWSTR subkey_x86 = TEXT("SOWTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\UCP");
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question, why the current code does not work: `RegOpenKey` and `RegQueryValueEx` are macros which are defined as `RegOpenKeyW` and `RegQueryValueExW` in Unicode builds and as `RegOpenKeyA` and `RegQueryValueExA` in non-Unicode builds.
These are different functions. The `W` versions expect wide strings.